# Benefits of using jBPM

Tags: jbpm

I am new to jBPM and i dont understand the advantage of using BPM. I am going to create the process with code .

When user will create a request, jBPM process will be created, then admin will approve the request by provinding and input to Human task.

we can achieve it using db as well, and will be more flexible. for searching etc etc.

Could anybody tell me the actuall benefits of Using jBPM and when we should use it

Regards
Ramandeep Singh

Answer (score 2):

- **Flexibility:** In order to have more task approved you'll need more variables that relates to the approbation flow not to the business logic. When the approbation needs to interact more than a Maker and Checker you just define a new actor in your flow.
- **Task timers:** When you have due dates to task, and the task need to be interrupted, business logic comes difficult to achieve.
- **Multiple flows** When you need to divergent your flow to multiple actors, manageability comes difficult to achieve.
- **Conditions and Rules** Rules and conditions are more comprehensive when they are draw in BPMN.

In abstract if your business process is changing frequently you should consider to use a BPM Suite.

Answer (score 1):

jBPM is a flexible Business Process Management (BPM) Suite. It makes the bridge between business analysts and developers. Traditional BPM engines have a focus that is limited to non-technical people only. jBPM has a dual focus: it offers process management features in a way that both business users and developers like it.
Suppose if you are applying for a car loan, then there will be sequence of steps you should follow to get approve from bank, steps might be many.. and at every step we need to store some data about that step..
This will be complex if you use database for handling this..
Using jBPM, it will take care of everything intermediate values and decisions based on the input provided by you..

you can refer [This Link](http://jbpm.jboss.org/)

Hope this helps you..

Comment: So you mean that we don't have to save values to db in case we use jBPM and jBPM will take care of everything?

Comment: Absolutely... It will take care of the data.. you just need to tell that what data you want to save. so you can use it through out the process...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve same approval process from DB as well but what if want to add new approval step. BPM tools are very flexible in these type of scenario. You don't need developer to add additional step.

You can use BAM tool to check everything of processes which are currently running. You can use jBPM API to get workitems details from jBPM database.

First thing you need to understand benefits of using BPM tools then you check what is benefits of jBPM. :)